# What is the strong solution for this SDE

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to calculate $E_t[(X_T-K)^+]$ where
$$dX_t=\frac{3}{X_t}dt+2X_t dW_t$$
and $X_0=x$.  I don't  know how extact the strong solution of  this SDE. Indeed I used Ito's lemma but it was not usefule.

Thanks for attantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
d\left(X_t^2\right) &= 2X_t dX_t + d\langle X, X\rangle_t\\
&=(6+4X_t^2)dt + 4X_t^2dW_t,
\end{align*}
which can be solved using the technique with an *integral factor*. Specifically, note that
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{4t-4W_t}X_t^2 \right) &= X_t^2 d\left(e^{4t-4W_t}\right) + e^{4t-4W_t} d(X_t^2) + \left\langle d\left(e^{4t-4W_t}\right), d(X_t^2) \right\rangle\\
&=e^{4t-4W_t}X_t^2(12dt-4dW_t)\\
&\quad +e^{4t-4W_t}\left[(6+4X_t^2)dt + 4X_t^2dW_t\right]- 16  e^{4t-4W_t}X_t^2 dt\\
&=6e^{4t-4W_t} dt.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
e^{4t-4W_t}X_t^2 &= x^2+6\int_0^t e^{4s-4W_s} ds.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
X_t^2 = e^{4W_t-4t}\left(x^2+6\int_0^t e^{4s-4W_s} ds \right).
\end{align*}

> A general note. For an equation of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> dY_t = (aY_t+b)dt + (cY_t+d) dW_t, 
> \end{align*}
>   we can apply an integral factor of the form $$e^{(-a+\frac{1}{2}c^2)t -cW_t}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Why should we use dynamic of $X_t^2$ instead of dynamic of $X_t^3$ or $X_t^4$?

Comment: That is based on the structure of your equation. With $X_t^2$, you can have an equation that have coefficients as linear functions of  $X_t^2$.  For $X_t^3$ and $X_t^4$, they do not have such nice property. The equation for $X_t^2$ does not come up arbitrarily: if you multiply $X_t$ to both sides of your equation, you instantly see the relationship with $X_t^2$.

Comment: How  should we know it?

Comment: This equation $X_tdX_t = 3dt +2 X_t^2 dW_t$ is the same as your original equation. Do you see the relationship with $X_t^2$? You may need a relatively good sense in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't say: "Ito's lemma wasn't useful". Set 
$$Y_t=-2W_t+2t\tag 1$$
Note $W_0=0$ thus $Y_0=0$.We have
$$dY_t=2\,dt-2\,dW_t\tag 2$$
Set $Z_t=e^{Y_t}$. By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$dZ_t=e^{Y_t}\,dY_t+\frac{1}{2}e^{Y_t}d[Y_t,Y_t]\tag 3$$
therefore
$$dZ_t=4e^{Y_t}dt-2\,e^{Y_t}dW_t=4Z_tdt-2Z_tdW_t\tag 4$$
on the other hand
$$d(X_t\,Z_t)=Z_t\,dX_t+X_t\,dZ_t+d[X_t,Z_t]\tag 5$$
thus
$$d(X_t\,Z_t)=\frac{3Z_t}{X_t}dt\tag 6$$
in other words
$$d(X_t\,Z_t)=\frac{3Z_t^2}{X_tZ_t}dt\tag 7$$
set $R_t=X_tZ_t$. We have
$$dR_t=\frac{3Z_t^2}{R_t}dt\tag 8$$
This can be solved as a regular ODE with separable variables :
$$R_t\,dR_t=3Z_t^2\, dt$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}R_t^2-\frac{1}{2}R_0^2=3\int_0^{t}Z_s^2ds\\
\frac{1}{2}R_t^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2=3\int_0^{t}Z_s^2ds\tag 9$$
then
$$X_t^2=e^{-2Y_t}\left(x^2+6\int_0^{t}e^{2Y_s}ds\right)\tag {10}$$
Finally

> $$\color{red}{X_t^2=e^{4W_t-4t}\left(x^2+6\int_0^{t}e^{-4W_s+4s}ds\right)\tag{11}}$$

Now How can you calculate $\mathbb{E}_t[(X_T-K)^+]?$

Comment: Sorry Gordon's solution is easier than yours.

Comment: No problem  --:)